# File not saving properly in C

Tags: c, fopen

The problem I'm having is that the data is not being stored properly,
What I want is it to still have the information no matter when you run the code.
Here is the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
typedef struct{
int select;
char NoteNames[20];
char NoteTexts[200];
}Notes;
char Input[20];
bool RUN = true;
#define ARRAYLEN 2
Notes a[ARRAYLEN];
int main(void) {
    int i;
  FILE *fp;
  while(RUN == true){
  printf("\nWould you like to view notes or take notes?\n<view/take/leave>\n");
  scanf("%s",Input);
  if (strncmp(Input, "view",1)==0){
    fp = fopen ("Notes.dat", "a+");
    printf("Here are the notes\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<(ARRAYLEN-1); i++){
        fread(&a[i], sizeof(a), 1, fp );
        printf("%s : %s \n",a[i].NoteNames,a[i].NoteTexts);
    }
    fclose(fp);
  }
  if (strncmp(Input, "take",1)==0){
    fp = fopen ("Notes.dat", "a");
    printf("\nNote name : ");
    scanf("%s",a[i].NoteNames);
    printf("\nNote text : ");
    scanf("%s",a[i].NoteTexts);
    fclose(fp);
  }
  if (strncmp(Input, "leave",1)==0){
    RUN = false;
  }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried things like changing the fopen type (i.e. r/r+ a/a+) but I cannot find out what is wrong with the code.
Sorry If I'm doing it totally wrong, this is mainly a mismatch of code that I could find on the internet xD.

Edit:
The output was all normal and what I was expecting, but the problem like I said is that the data was not being saved.

```
---HERE IS WHAT IT OUTPUTS---
Would you like to view notes or take notes?
<view/take/leave>
 take
Enter the notes name:
 lol
Enter the notes text:
 kek
Would you like to view notes or take notes?
<view/take/leave>
 view
lol : kek
Would you like to view notes or take notes?
<view/take/leave>
leave
>
---NEXT RUN---
Would you like to view notes or take notes?
<view/take/leave>
view
 : 
Would you like to view notes or take notes?
<view/take/leave>
---END OF OUTPUT---
```

Comment: "a" sets the file pointer to the end of the file, if you want to read/write then use "r+" or use fseek to position the file pointer.

Comment: Could you tell us what it _is_ doing? Show us some sample input and output?

Comment: There's a lot about your code that doesn't make sense. For example, you have a `for` loop that appears to run once for every entry you want to read. But in the loop, you read `sizeof(a)` bytes, which is the size of the array, not one entry. Also, have you yet decided on the file format you want to use? Did you document it?

Comment: You forgot to write your data to the file, you just open it and close it. (And you forgot to initialise your variables.)

Comment: You need to write to the file. a is for appending. Check the existences of file also.

Comment: Always check return status of IO functions (except plain printf), and do something (like just exit with message) on errors and other unexpected cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code for write file

```
FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen("program.txt", "w");
if(fptr == NULL)
{ 
printf("Error!");
exit(1);
} 
printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
gets(sentence);
fprintf(fptr,"%s", sentence);
fclose(fptr);
```

And 
Read file by below

```
char c[1000];
FILE *fptr;
if ((fptr = fopen("program.txt", "r")) == NULL) 
{
printf("Error! opening file");
//Program exits if file pointer returns NULL. 
exit(1);
} 
// reads text until newline fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]", c); 
printf("Data from the file:\n%s", c); 
fclose(fptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read your code carefully and go through it line by line:

- In the first `if` you open, read and close your file.
- In the second `if` you just open and then close your file.

  - There is no write to it.

Comment: Note that the first `fopen()` places the read/write position at the end of the file. It doesn't matter how much data was in the file — there is nothing to read after EOF.  That `fopen()` should use `"r"` or perhaps `"r+"` as the open mode; the `+` would create the file (empty) if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use fprintf to write your contents to your file.